# Does M. Bison want to kill the American presidential candidate?

Tags: plot-explanation, street-fighter-2-the-animated-movie

In *Street Fighter II: The Animated Movie (1994)* does M. Bison want to have American presidential candidate Ed Pressman killed, or does he want to keep him alive?

His scientist mentions something about this, but which direction were they leaning? Protect Pressman from assassination, or assassinate him?

The idea being that if Pressman gets elected it will either help or hurt Shadaloo.

Answer (score 2):

As the story revolves around Bison/Vega hypnotizing various characters  (much like the game plot), it's most likely means that he wants to **hypnotize** the President in order to control him. For shadowlaw's benefit. Killing the President would have the opposite affect. In the movie, Cammy and Ken are hypnotized in the same way.